# There exists $\theta$ between $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$ such that $\cos\theta=\theta$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that there exists $\theta$ between $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$ such that $\cos\theta=\theta$.

I tried to use intermediate value theorem on the interval $[\pi/4,\pi/2]$  without success.

Any suggestion how to proceed? maybe change the interval?

Thanks

Comment: This is false. You can easily see that $cos(\theta)-\theta < 0$ for $\theta \in [\pi/4, \pi/2]$

Comment: Unsurprising, since it's not true.  Over that interval, $\cos \theta < \sqrt{2}/2 < \pi/4$.

Comment: cos(x)=x only at x=0.74 which is slightly less than $\pi/4$

Comment: @WW1 thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\theta)=\cos\theta-\theta$. Then on our interval $f'(\theta)$ is negative, so $f$ is decreasing. We don't even need the derivative, since $\cos\theta$ is decreasing and $\theta$ is increasing, so the difference is decreasing.

Calculation shows that $f(\pi/4)$ is negative, so there is no root of $f(\theta)$ in the interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$.

Comment: You are welcome.  Note that $f(\pi/4)$ is not much below $0$. If we back up a bit, we do find a solution of $\cos\theta=\theta$.